# I can't free the memory

Tags: c

I'm in my 1st year of faculty and I have this homework:

> Write a program that reads n arrays of characters and concatenates them into another dynamically allocated array. Repeat the operation as many times as the user desires.
>
> After each displaying of the result, the allocated memory is freed.

And that is what I did:

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char** p, * v;
    int n, m;
    printf("\n\t enter the number of the arrays : \t");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n\t enter the maximum lenght of the arrays :");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    p = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);

    for (int i{}; i < n; i++)
        p[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * m);

    char t = 'Y';
    while (t == 'Y')
    {
        size_t z = 0;
        printf("\n\t enter your arrays :");
        for (int i{}; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%s", p[i]);
            z += strlen(p[i]);
        }
        v=(char* )malloc(z * sizeof(char));
        for (int i{}; i < n; i++)
            if (i == 0)
                strcpy(v, p[i]);
            else
                strcat(v, p[i]);
        if (v) {
            puts(v);
            free(v);
        }

        if (p)
            for (int i{}; i < n; i++)
                free(p[i]);

        printf("\n\t wanna continue ? (Y/N)");
        scanf("%d", &t);
    }
}
```

When I want to free the memory to use again, I get a "head corruption error" from the debugger.

Any idea why?

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: `p = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);` needs to be `p = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);` or better still `p = malloc(sizeof(*p) * n);`

Comment: I am using Visual Studio because of my teacher , and i need the cast before the malloc .

Comment: This appears to be `C`.  Edit your post to eliminate the `C++` tag.

Comment: In project properties change to compile for C.

Comment: "*i need the cast before the malloc*. That's not the main point. The `sizeof` is wrong. But the cast is not needed for C code. It seems you are compiling as C++ code.

Comment: @kaylum it is default in VS.

Comment: @0___________ Yes but the OP is perhaps not aware of that. OP needs to work out what language they really want to be coding and compiling and sort that out first. If it is C++ then fine, update the question to say that. If it is C then the IDE needs to be set up correctly to do that.

Comment: You have freed `p[i]`, but then you never follow that up with `free(p);`  Keep in mind that for every call to `malloc()`, there should be a corresponding call to `free()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Allocation size mistake**

Code allocated the wrong size.  `p` is a pointer, not a `char`.
Cast not needed either.

```
char** p; 
...
p = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);  // Bad
```

Size to the type of the referenced object. It is easier to code right, review and maintain than attempting to code the matching type.

```
p = malloc(sizeof *p * n);  // Good
...
  p[i] = malloc(sizeof *p[i] * m);
```

Robust code would also check for errors.

```
if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "No numeric input or negative count\n");
  // Perhaps exit here.
}

p = malloc(sizeof *p * n);
if (p == NULL && n > 0) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed\n);
  // Perhaps exit here.
}
```

Other [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645128/ryyker) may exists.

**Off-by-1**

`v` under allocates by 1 as it does not account for the terminating *null character*.   This also applies to `p[i] = malloc(sizeof *p[i] * m);` which likely should be `p[i] = malloc(sizeof *p[i] * (m+1));`

```
    // size_t z = 0;
    size_t z = 1;
```

**Simplify**

Rather than a special case for `i==0`, simply set `v[0] = 0` first.

```
    v = malloc(sizeof *v * z /* or z + 1, see above */ );
    if (v) {
      // Handle error
    }
    v[0] = '\0';
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      strcat(v, p[i]);
    }
    puts(v);
    free(v);
```

Other simplifications and [improvements](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm) possible.

Comment: i get the error " E0513 a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char **" if i don't use cast .

Comment: @RăzvanCâcu Use a C compiler for C code. "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char **" indicates you are using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @RăzvanCâcu -   VS must have settings to allow for compiling `C`, does it not?

Comment: it does  , but idk if it s a good idea to change it , because i need to send it to my teacher who uses the default vs compiler .

Comment: @RăzvanCâcu If your teachers teaches C using a C++ compiler you should tell the teacher to read about the differences. They are two different languages and it's an utterly bad idea to teach a language using a compiler for a different language.

Comment: @RăzvanCâcu Ask your teacher if you should compile your C code with a compiler in C mode or use the default setting and compiler in another language.

Comment: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170) appears to say that, "ANSI C89, but includes several Microsoft extensions, some of which are part of ISO C99" is "used by default for code that has a .c file extension, unless overridden." OP, are you using the the `.c` extension in your filenames?

Comment: @Neil yes i did .

Comment: @RăzvanCâcu  What was the teacher's response?

Comment: He didn't respond , but i guess i will use the c compiler .

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the answer you need to change in the program properties option which selects what is the language C/C++

[image]

Comment: Thanks , i did change the compiler but i have the same issue  , heap  corruption detected .

Comment: It is to avoid casts of malloc

Answer (score 1):

I get warnings, maybe I forgot some checks (malloc/scanf).

I hope I helped you even though I’m a beginner.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

struct cstring {

    char* data;
    size_t size;

};

bool create_cstring(struct cstring* const object, const size_t size) {

    return (object->data = calloc(size, sizeof(char))) ?
        (object->size = size + 1U) :
        (object->size = 0U);

}

bool destroy_cstring(struct cstring* const object) {

    free(object->data);
    object->size = 0U;

}

struct cvector_string {

    struct cstring* data;
    size_t size;

};

bool create_cvector_string(struct cvector_string* const object, const size_t size) {

    return (object->data = calloc(size, sizeof(struct cstring))) ?
        (object->size = size) :
        (object->size =   0U) ;

}

void destroy_cvector_string(struct cvector_string* const object) {

    free(object->data);
    object->size = 0U;

}

int main()
{

    struct cvector_string cv = { NULL, 0U };

    // Allocations 
    {

        // Allocate n arrays of chars
        {

            size_t cv_n = 0;

            printf("\n\t Enter the number of the arrays : \t"); 
            scanf("%zu", &cv_n);

            if (!create_cvector_string(&cv, cv_n)) {

                fprintf(stderr, "Error : Bad allocation\n");
                return 1;

            }

        }

        // Allocate arrays of n chars
        {

            size_t cv_m = 0;

            printf("\n\t Enter the maximum lenght of the arrays : \t");
            scanf("%zu", &cv_m);

            for (struct cstring* it = cv.data; it != cv.data + cv.size; ++it) {

                if (!create_cstring(it, cv_m)) {

                    fprintf(stderr, "Error : Bad allocation\n");
                    return 1;

                }

            }

        }

    }

    struct cstring r = { NULL, 0U };


    {

        char cont = '\0';

        do {

            /* Initialize arrays of chars, calculate the length of the resulting string
             * and create the resulting string */
            {

                size_t length_sum = 0;

                for (struct cstring* it = cv.data; it != cv.data + cv.size; ++it) {

                    scanf("%s", it->data);
                    length_sum += strlen(it->data);

                }

                if (!create_cstring(&r, length_sum)) {

                    fprintf(stderr, "Error : Bad allocation\n");
                    return 1;

                }

            }

            // Initialize and concatenate the resulting string
            {

                strcpy(r.data, cv.data[0].data); 
                // or using destination = strcpy(malloc, source), same for strcat

                for (struct cstring* it = cv.data + 1; it != cv.data + cv.size; ++it) strcat(r.data, it->data);

            }


            // Print and deallocate the resulting string

            puts(r.data);
            destroy_cstring(&r);

            // Prompt to continue

            printf("\n\t Wanna continue? (Y/N) ");
            scanf(" %c", &cont);

        } while (cont == 'Y');

    }

    // Deallocations 
    {

        // Deallocate all the arrays of chars
        for (struct cstring* it = cv.data; it != cv.data + cv.size; ++it) destroy_cstring(it);

        // Deallocate the array of arrays of chars
        destroy_cvector_string(&cv);

    }

}
```

Errors :

1. You’re freeing the allocated memory for character arrays and then reading into that memory.

Deallocating

```
 for (int i{}; i < n; i++)
                free(p[i]);
```

Using

```
 for (int i{}; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%s", p[i]);
            z += strlen(p[i]);
        }
```

2. You have to allocate memory for pointers, not allocate memory for characters.

   ```
   p = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much !!!

Comment: You’re welcome ^^

Comment: ok so basically i though if i use free i just remove the already read elements and not deallocate the memory ,sorry.

Comment: `struct cvector_string` and `struct cstring` are obfuscating your C with C++ language in a way that's going to be hard to debug and understand in larger programmes, but at least you didn't `typedef` them.

Comment: I know Neil, simply changes the structures for members  if you don’t like it. But this isn’t a "large program".

Comment: I think this code could be shortened quite a bit by making `struct cstring` just a `char *`, since you don't appear to use `size` anywhere. (Sorry if I sounded negative.)

Comment: I’m sorry about that.
And yes, you’re right cstring is removable, I used it because for some it can be problematic to work with pointer to pointer notation.

Answer (score 0):

Update : I did it  !
That's  the final code :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool ver(bool);

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    char** myarray;
    bool y = true;


    while (y == true) {
        printf("enter the number of arrays : ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        myarray = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
        if (myarray == NULL && n > 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("enter the  maximum size of the  arrays : ");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        for (int i = { 0 }; i < n; i++)
            myarray[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(char));


        printf("\n\t enter your stings : \n");
        size_t x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (myarray[i])
                scanf("%s", myarray[i]);
            x += sizeof(myarray[i]);
        }
        char* v;
        v = malloc(x * sizeof(char));
        if (v == NULL && x > 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        strcpy(v, myarray[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            strcat(v, myarray[i]);
        puts(v);
        free(v);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            free(myarray[i]);
        free(myarray);
        y = ver(y);



    }
}
bool ver(bool r) {
    char var;
    printf("\n\twanna continue ? (Y/N)\n");
    scanf(" %c", &var); 
    while(var != 'Y' && var != 'N')
    {
        printf("\n\tInvalid input  !\n wanna continue ?(Y/N).");
        scanf(" %c", &var);
    }

    if (var == 'N')
        r = false;
    else
        r= true;
    return r;
}
```

I am still new to C , if you have any suggestion please tell .